# Shift Google Documents header up/down one level

Tags: google-docs, headers

Let's say I formatted a document this way:

```
1. Title (style: title 1)
    1.1 Subtitle (style: title 2)
    1.2 Subtitle (style: title 2)
```

And I want to insert an extra level between Title and Subtitle 1:

```
1. Title (style: title 1)
    1.1 New subtitle
        1.1.1 Subtitle (style: title 2)
        1.1.2 Subtitle (style: title 2)
```

Is there a way/plugin to avoid to manually change the style of every header that has been shifted down one level?

Comment: I use the styles toolbar then I generate a table of contents